# How to autopopulate an HTML form and submit it instantly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form with a username and password.

This HTML form contains a login for both free and paid users. Paid users need to enter a username and password, while free users have to enter default usernames e.g. Username = myname, and Password = password.

I managed to auto populate the values of the form using an HTML link -

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('name').value='myname';document.getElementById('password').value='mypassword';" >Free User</a>
```

This worked smoothly. Now I would like to add the possibility that when the Free User clicks the button, the values are auto populated as above and the said HTML form is submitted immediately.

When I tried it using various methods, the fields would populate but the HTML form will not submit.

Thanks you.

Comment: i dont think you got this right, if it is the free user, no log in should be needed, just set it on the server side

Comment: Hi @Ibu, I know it may not make sense for you, but in my objective of the design of the software every user has to have a username and password, even free users. So they are given a default username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the defaults in the form, no script required:

```
User ID: <input type="text" name="userid" value="guest">
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="password">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

If you really *really* must use script, then (noting that a form control with a name of "name" will mask the form's name property so I've used something more suitable) use something like:

```
<input type="button" value="Guest Login" onclick="
  this.form.userid.value = 'guest';
  this.form.password.value = 'password';
  this.form.submit();
">
```

But frankly it's a complete waste of time. If you put two submit buttons in the form, one for guests and one for registered users, then guests can click the guest submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="registeredLogin" value="Registered User Login">
<input type="submit" name="guestLogin" value="Guest User Login">
```

Whichever button is clicked will be sent to the server so it can set appropriate permissions. If they've clicked the guest button, you don't care what value they set for username or password, just ignore it.

Again, zero script required.

Comment: I suppose the downvote is because I dared to suggest a script-free answer. Or maybe I didn't include someone's favourite library, or they had a bad day, whatever. I think I can cop a 2 point penalty. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, and you want a button to populate the form fields before posting the form - just place your embedded code in a javascript function and set it as the click handler via the 'onclick' property of the button.

**Ex:**

```
<script>
    function populate(){
        document.getElementById('name').value='myname';  //set username
        document.getElementById('password').value='mypassword'; //setpassword
        document.forms["formID"].submit();  //submit 'formID'
    }
</script>

...

<form>
    ....
    <input type="button" name="test" value="Free User" onclick="populate()">
</form>
<!-- or as a link.. -->
<a href="#" onclick="populate()" title="login as free user">Free User</a>
```

Id question a design that means you need to populate the variables and not have them as defaults though! (Defaults can be set in the HTML) However, if that's the design spec then here's your code!

**Edit**
To summarise all the comments below: this code wont work if you have an element in your form with the name 'submit' - ala most submit forms which get named submit! If you try and call this code the submit line will actually try and call the button; which is obviously not a function and you'll get this error here...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object <#an HtmlFormElement> is not a function.
```

[[jsFiddle with the error](http://jsfiddle.net/KS5ZN/3/)] [[jsFiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/KS5ZN/2/)] - **Note only the submit button name has changed**.

The explanation for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993047/1475897) - well you learn something new everyday!

So you can either set the name of your button to something else - i.e. sub; or you can use GitaarLAB's solution of calling the click event on the submit button programmatically. (See the comments section for this)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like that when I click the html link the I want to populate the files AND submit the HTML form.

Comment: Edited and done :) The code is in a separate function to make it a little neater than having it embedded as a HTML property.

Comment: I don't want them as defaults. I want that whenever someone clicks the link - the form fields are filled with the said values (which I managed to do) and submit the HTML form instantly when clicking the same link (which I haven't manged to do). Thanks.

Comment: Thats what the code will do. Do you want it on a button or a link? edit - done them both.

Comment: Thanks but it still not submitting!

Comment: Have you set the form ID and is the error console displaying anything?

Comment: I did... should it be document.forms["formID"].submit(); or document.forms['formID'].submit();

Comment: No real difference, I would try an alert() statement in the function to make sure it's getting called. Are the form inputs getting changed? If so check the form submit line again :/

Comment: They are getting changed, no problem. The problem is when they are not getting submitted only. Thanks.

Comment: did you set the form's properties like action...?

Comment: Without seeing more HTML it's very difficult to work out what's going wrong! It's obviously that one line, but the line itself is definitely correct! ([Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit))

Comment: `<form name="input" id="formID" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">` method could also be post..   with get, you can see the data (url-encoded) in the addressbar, with post, you don't.

Comment: Ah, I figured you had that in the form already. @GitaarLab is dead on about putting the form action in the mark-up.

Comment: This is the code @FergusMorrow.
`
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="formID" name="formID">
<label for="name">Username:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text">   <label for="user_email">Password:</label>
<input id="user_email" name="email" type="password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
    </form>
   
 
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(){
        document.getElementById('name').value='duddu';
        document.getElementById('user_email').value='dudu';
        document.forms["formID"].submit();    }
</script>`

Comment: hard to read, but looks ok EDIT: doublechecked with http://jsbeautifier.org/ looks still ok, give it a go!

Comment: humor me, try making the password field a hidden input-field. I've been researching this stuff last month. With this you can test if your browser (which one?) blocks javascript modified passwordfields. A lot of them also 'break' file-inputs nowadays

Comment: I tried it on Google Chrome and id didn't work, even on Mozilla. I changed type="password"  to type="text" still doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried with my local php echo script, no values are submitted, I'll be working on it now.

Comment: Fixed. It's because your submit button is called submit. [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718799/unable-to-submit-an-html-form-after-intercepting-the-submit-with-javascript) Rename your submit button and try! If you look at the developer console it tells you that submit isn't a function - it's because it's a button in your form! :) [jsFiddle Showing Function Working](http://jsfiddle.net/KS5ZN/) - Note, it is just with the submit button renamed 'sub'

Comment: hmm, I had a bingo to: `<button onclick="populate(); document.getElementById('submit').click(); ">asdf</button>` done. 
The trick is to add an ID to your submit-button, and then trigger it's click-event instead of submit();

Comment: haha, I like your style @GitaarLAB - another workaround for the same problem! I never thought having a child element named like a DOM function would essentially overwrite that function - it makes sense I guess.. but still! O_o

Comment: @Fergus Morrow: 
you don't overwrite it, you call the click() event of the submit button. Hence the form continues normal operation :P
So change line `document.forms["formID"].submit();` with `document.getElementById('submit').click();`   and don't forget to set the id on the submit-button!   Out of interest.. is there a split answer function here on SO?

Comment: I didn't mean overwrite it, I meant the fact that there was an element seemed to overwrite access to the submit() function; i.e when trying to call .submit() it was actually accessing the child element (which was the button named submit) - [Explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718799/unable-to-submit-an-html-form-after-intercepting-the-submit-with-javascript). No idea about a split answer function!

Comment: Let's leave it to the op which of the 2 fixes he thinks is better :) At least I enjoyed collaborating :P

Comment: Excellent it worked for me! As you both mentioned I have to change the name of the submit button from 'submit' to something else!!! Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can still set them serverside, ie if a login-form submit is received without username/password, then override it with your default user/pass and continue your login-script.

Alternatively or on top of this, you could also set 1 or 2 extra hidden fields if you should wish to assign different default user/pass combinations dynamically.

More directly to your question, you already figured out how to populate one field.. so a second field is repeating the same trick. You can still use the default submit-buton from the form if you'd like to, but then you need Javascript running on the client. Submitting the form is traditionally done by document.forms[n].submit();
Yet document.getElementById('submit').click(); works so much better..

So all in all, for a graceful fallback, I'd advise 2 hidden form-fields and take care of the rest serverside.

Good luck

**UPDATE 3:**  Two versions based on my technique, now works perfectly!!!
Auto-logon:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="formID" name="formID">
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
    <label for="user_email">Password:</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="email" type="password" />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('name').value = 'duddu';
    document.getElementById('user_email').value = 'dudu';
    document.getElementById('submit').click();
};
</script>
```

Button (user initiated) auto-logon:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="formID" name="formID">
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
    <label for="user_email">Password:</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="email" type="password" />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input name="free" type="button" value="Free User Login" onclick="popAndSub();" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var popAndSub=function(){
    document.getElementById('name').value = 'duddu';
    document.getElementById('user_email').value = 'dudu';
    document.getElementById('submit').click();
};
</script>
```

Comment: window.onload? Surely the paid users wont get a chance to type their details in? ;) Code is good though, just attach the function to a link perhaps?

Comment: @Fergus Morrow: 
yep, just noticed that to, was still in the inspiration of the code we both were working on 10 minutes ago. This looked like it was meant to trigger automatically, thus I forgot about the op wanting a link. So my first Bingo with the button was still correct. Now we have 2 solutions :P With button and.. without button (which is nice in auto-login scripts generated by your personal coded password-vault called 'ecto gammat' .. I'll update my answer once more to include both options :P