# How to submit a form that has been intercepted with event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit, preventdefault

I have a plain vanilla form with id="edit_profile".

When the form is submitted I want to intercept it and check whether I need to geocode an address via the google maps api, and if not go ahead and submit anyway.

Something like:

```
$('#edit_profile').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( some test ) {
        geocode_address( address, this ); // the api callback will handle form submit
    } else {
    // we want to go ahead and submit the form
    this.submit();
    }
});
```

The problem is `this.submit()` is throwing the error `TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function`

I read something recently but can't now find about having to use native JavaScript to submit the form rather than jQuery (I'm guessing because the jQuery event handler for the form submit has already been told to preventDefault).

But if I try some variant like `document.getElementById('edit_profile').submit();` or `document.forms[0].submit();` I get the same error or thereabouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because the solution was so unexpected and simple it bears repeating. Full credit to Chris Butler for answering this related question: [Unable to `submit()` an html form after intercepting the submit with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718799/unable-to-submit-an-html-form-after-intercepting-the-submit-with-javascript) (note, his wasn't the accepted answer).

Answer: if you name & #id your submit buttons "submit" that will clash with the name of the native JavaScript .submit() method which will no longer work and give the type error described in the question.

So the solution in my case was to rename my submit button to something else.

To recap:

To intercept a form submission you could intercept the click on the submit button or intercept the form submission itself. If your objective is to intercept the form submission then do that, not the click event on the submit button, as forms can be submitted by other events such as hitting enter on a textfield.

If you intercept the form via jQuery with, e.g. `$("#myForm").on("submit", function() {...})` and then go on to pass off the submit handling to another function (e.g. as in the question where a call to a geocoding api is made) then *that* function will need to trigger the form submission via acting on the DOM form element directly (e.g. `document.getElementById('myForm').submit() ) which will submit the form without triggering the onsubmit event so that the initial intercept isn't triggered again creating an infinite loop as it would be if you used jQuery to trigger the submit.

Answer (score 1):

DOM Elements have no method `.submit` -- but jQuery objects do (only on `form` elements) -- basically, you forgot to wrap `this` in jQuery:

```
$(this).submit();
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Edit:

I see where you are getting the "infinite-loop" scenario from. You should actually be setting the handler up to trigger when you click the Submit `button` and not the forms actual submit.

As of now, you catch the forms `submit` action and prevent the default action (which is submitting) -- then you do some stuff and call `submit` on `this`. Well that will trigger the handler for the form `submit`, which prevents the default action again! So, in short, put a handler on your Submit button, prevent the default action, do logic, then call `$("#edit_profile").submit()`

Comment: Really? I've read often about native javascript form submit, e.g. here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Wrapping 'this' to make it a jQuery object sets up an infinite loop.

Comment: Wrapping `this` into a jQuery object does NOT setup an infinite loop, you need to use `$(this)` all the time in jQuery!

Comment: but you don't need jquery to use `this`, you only need to use `$(this)` if you want to manipulate `this` using jquery. Infinite loop might be the wrong name for the error, but it's far too long for me to paste here in any case. Using $(this) means I'm intercepting the form submit, then submitting it, intercepting that submit, submitting it, intercepting _that_ submit, submitting etc etc.

Comment: @terraling - Think we both may be a bit confused, is `this` referencing your `form` element, or the button that was clicked? Your function should be being ran when you click the submit button, then you prevent the default action, then target the form and call `submit` -- dont prevent default on the form itself.

Comment: Firstly, thanks btw for spending time on this. I'll play around with intercepting the click rather than the submit, although I'd point out that the jquery docs for submit() https://api.jquery.com/submit/) use examples of intercepting the form submit not the button click so it might be required in this case but I wouldn't dismiss it in general. I'll report back...

Comment: @terraling -- Just read thru the doc's some more, try `return true` if you want your form to submit, rather than `this.submit()`

Comment: native JS element has sumit() method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not rearrange the code something like this

```
$('#edit_profile').on('submit', function(event) {
  if ( some test ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    geocode_address( address, this ); // the api callback will handle form submit
  } else {
    // we want to go ahead and submit the form
    // this.submit(); // no need to call explicitly
  }
});
```

It won't work, if you want to have callback in `some test` but it doesn't look like that from your code.

Comment: Thanks amitamb. Quick note to point out that in your example the else { } clause is actually redundant because, after failing the if test, at the end of the anonymous function there's an implicit return true which will trigger the submit anyway.